# How to have button in listview for some items in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I'm creating a social network app for android , I have a listview where the posts are displayed , What I want to do is to give the user the possibilty of removing his own posts, I don't know how to do the button remove in some posts and not all of them . I hope you understunded my issue , any help would be much appreciated .
Thank you.

This is the adapter for feed :

```
public class FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private static final String TAG = FeedListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
PopupWindow popWindow = null;
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
private String URL = "http://192.168.1.10/social/like.php";
private String user_id;
ViewHolder holder;
private int[] mHighlightedPositions = new int[6];
private String test;

private CommentsListAdapter listAdapter;
private List<CommentsListItem> commentsitems;


private LikesListAdapter listAdapter1;
private List<FriendsListItem> likesitems;



private String URL1 = "http://192.168.1.10/social/comments.php";
private String URL2 = "http://192.168.1.10/social/comment.php";
private String URL3 = "http://192.168.1.10/social/likes.php";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";


FeedItem item;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public FeedListAdapter(Activity activity, List<FeedItem> feedItems, String user_id) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.feedItems = feedItems;
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return feedItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return feedItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public void refresh(List<FeedItem> newlist) {
    feedItems.addAll(newlist);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public List<FeedItem> getData() {
    return feedItems;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
final View vi = convertView;
    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null){
         convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.posts_row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.name = (Button)convertView .findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.timestamp = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.time);
        holder.statusMsg = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.status);
        holder. url = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.url);
        holder.profilePic = (CircleImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.profile_img);
        holder.feedImageView = (FeedImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.image);


        holder.nbr_likes = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nbr_likes);
        holder.nbr_comments = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.nbr_comments);

        holder.like =(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.like);
        holder.comment =(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{

        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Button row pos click: " + getCount());

    holder.like.setTag(position);
    SharedPreferences prefs = activity.getSharedPreferences("mHighlightedPositions2", activity.MODE_PRIVATE);


    String savedString = prefs.getString("string", "");
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(savedString, ",");
    int[] savedList = new int[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        while(st.hasMoreTokens())
            mHighlightedPositions[i] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    }


    if(mHighlightedPositions[position] == 1) {
       holder.like.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.like2, 0, 0, 0);
        holder.like.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF5722"));


        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }else {
       holder.like.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.like1, 0, 0, 0);
       holder.like.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8B8B8F"));
       notifyDataSetChanged();

    }





    holder.nbr_likes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            item = feedItems.get(position);

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View inflatedView = null;
            PopupWindow popWindow = null;
            // inflate the custom popup layout
            inflatedView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.likes, null, false);
            // find the ListView in the popup layout
            ListView listView = (ListView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.likesListView);

            TextView emptyList = (TextView)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.empty);
            listView.setEmptyView(emptyList);




            // get device size
            Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            final Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            int mDeviceHeight = size.y;


            // fill the data to the list items
            setLikesList(listView);


            // set height depends on the device size
            if(inflatedView!=null)
                popWindow = new PopupWindow(inflatedView, size.x - 50, size.y - 400, true);
            // set a background drawable with rounders corners
            popWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fb_popup_bg));
            // make it focusable to show the keyboard to enter in `EditText`
            popWindow.setFocusable(true);
            // make it outside touchable to dismiss the popup window
            popWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

            // show the popup at bottom of the screen and set some margin at bottom ie,
            if(popWindow!=null)
                popWindow.showAtLocation(inflatedView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 100);



        }
    });



        holder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                item = feedItems.get(position);


              int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
                Log.d(TAG, "Button row pos click: " + getCount());
                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) v.getParent();
                Button button = (Button) layout.getChildAt(0);
                if (mHighlightedPositions[position] == 1) {
                   test ="delete";
                    item.setNbrLikes(item.getNbrLikes()-1);
                    button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.like1, 0, 0, 0);
                    button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8B8B8F"));
                    mHighlightedPositions[position] = 0;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    test ="add";
                    item.setNbrLikes(item.getNbrLikes()+1);
                    button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.like2, 0, 0, 0);
                    button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF5722"));
                    mHighlightedPositions[position] = 1;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                }




                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("post_id", item.getId());
                params.put("user_id", user_id);
                params.put("test", test);
                Toast.makeText(activity, item.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(activity, user_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // making fresh volley request and getting json
                CustomRequest jsonReq = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                        URL, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                        if (response != null) {

                            parseJsonFeed(response);


                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                });

                // Adding request to volley request queue
                AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);


            }

        });



    holder.comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                item = feedItems.get(position);
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View inflatedView = null;
                // inflate the custom popup layout
                inflatedView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.comment, null, false);
                // find the ListView in the popup layout
                ListView listView = (ListView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.commentsListView);
                TextView nbr_likes_pop = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.nbr_likes_pop);

                TextView emptyList = (TextView)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.empty);
                listView.setEmptyView(emptyList);

                nbr_likes_pop.setText(item.getNbrLikes()+" Persons Like this");
                if (item.getNbrLikes() == 0)   nbr_likes_pop.setText("No Like For This Post Yet");


                ImageButton send = (ImageButton) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.send);
                final EditText writeComment =(EditText)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.writeComment);


                send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        item = feedItems.get(position);

                        if (writeComment.getText().toString() == "") {


                        } else {
                            item.setNbrComments(item.getNbrComments() + 1);

                            String comment = writeComment.getText().toString();
                            Long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            String time = ts.toString();
                            String post_id = item.getId();


                            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            params.put("post_id", post_id);
                            params.put("comment", comment);
                            params.put("time", time);
                            params.put("user_id", user_id);


                            CustomRequest jsonReq = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                                    URL2, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                    if (response != null) {

                                        parseJsonComment(response);

                                    }
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                                }
                            });

                            // Adding request to volley request queue
                            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);


                            popWindow.dismiss();


                        }

                    }
                });


                // get device size
                Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                final Point size = new Point();
                display.getSize(size);
                int mDeviceHeight = size.y;


                // fill the data to the list items
                setCommentList(listView);


                // set height depends on the device size
                if(inflatedView!=null)
                    popWindow = new PopupWindow(inflatedView, size.x - 50, size.y - 400, true);
                // set a background drawable with rounders corners
                popWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fb_popup_bg));
                // make it focusable to show the keyboard to enter in `EditText`
                popWindow.setFocusable(true);
                // make it outside touchable to dismiss the popup window
                popWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

                // show the popup at bottom of the screen and set some margin at bottom ie,
                if(popWindow!=null)
                    popWindow.showAtLocation(inflatedView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 100);


            }


        });




    holder.nbr_comments.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            item = feedItems.get(position);

            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View inflatedView = null;
            PopupWindow popWindow = null;
            // inflate the custom popup layout
            inflatedView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.comments, null, false);
            // find the ListView in the popup layout
            ListView listView = (ListView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.commentsListView);
            TextView nbr_likes_pop = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.nbr_likes_pop);

            TextView emptyList = (TextView)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.empty);
            listView.setEmptyView(emptyList);

            nbr_likes_pop.setText(item.getNbrLikes()+" Persons Like this");
            if (item.getNbrLikes() == 0)   nbr_likes_pop.setText("No Like For This Post Yet");


            // get device size
            Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            final Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            int mDeviceHeight = size.y;


            // fill the data to the list items
            setCommentList(listView);


            // set height depends on the device size
            if(inflatedView!=null)
                popWindow = new PopupWindow(inflatedView, size.x - 50, size.y - 400, true);
            // set a background drawable with rounders corners
            popWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fb_popup_bg));
            // make it focusable to show the keyboard to enter in `EditText`
            popWindow.setFocusable(true);
            // make it outside touchable to dismiss the popup window
            popWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

            // show the popup at bottom of the screen and set some margin at bottom ie,
            if(popWindow!=null)
                popWindow.showAtLocation(inflatedView, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 100);




        }


    });
    item = feedItems.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(item.getName());

        holder.nbr_likes.setText(item.getNbrLikes() + " Likes  - ");
        holder.nbr_comments.setText(item.getNbrComments() + " Comments");



        // Converting timestamp into x ago format
        CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                Long.parseLong(item.getTimeStamp()),
                System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
    holder.timestamp.setText(timeAgo);

        // Chcek for empty status message
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getStatus())) {
            holder.statusMsg.setText(item.getStatus());
            holder.statusMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // status is empty, remove from view
            holder.statusMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // Checking for null feed url
        if (item.getUrl() != null) {
            holder.url.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + item.getUrl() + "\">"
                    + item.getUrl() + "</a> "));

            // Making url clickable
            holder.url.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            holder.url.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // url is null, remove from the view
            holder.url.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // user profile pic
       holder.profilePic.setImageUrl(item.getProfilePic(), imageLoader);

        // Feed image
        if (item.getImge() != null) {
            holder.feedImageView.setImageUrl(item.getImge(), imageLoader);
            holder.feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.feedImageView
                    .setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            holder.feedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = activity.getSharedPreferences("mHighlightedPositions2", activity.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < mHighlightedPositions.length; i++) {
        str.append(mHighlightedPositions[i]).append(",");
    }
    editor.putString("string", str.toString());

    return convertView;
    }

void setCommentList(ListView listView){


    commentsitems = new ArrayList<CommentsListItem>();
    listAdapter = new CommentsListAdapter(activity, commentsitems);

    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);


    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("post_id", item.getId());
    // making fresh volley request and getting json
    CustomRequest jsonReq = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            URL1,params , new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            if (response != null) {

                parseJsonComments(response);

            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });

    // Adding request to volley request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);






}



void setLikesList(ListView listView){


    likesitems = new ArrayList<FriendsListItem>();
    listAdapter1 = new LikesListAdapter(activity, likesitems);

    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter1);


    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("post_id", item.getId());
    // making fresh volley request and getting json
    CustomRequest jsonReq = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            URL3,params , new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            if (response != null) {

                parseJsonLikes(response);

            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });

    // Adding request to volley request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);






}
    static class ViewHolder {
        Button name;
        TextView timestamp;
        TextView statusMsg;
        TextView url;
        CircleImageView profilePic;
        FeedImageView feedImageView;
        Button nbr_likes;
        Button nbr_comments;
        Button like;
        Button comment;
    }


private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
    int success;
    try {
        success = response.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success == 1) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "erreur", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        //listAdapter.addAll(feedItems);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void parseJsonComments(JSONObject response) {
    int success;

    try {
        success = response.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success == 1) {
            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("comments");

            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                CommentsListItem item = new CommentsListItem();
                item.setId(feedObj.getString("comment_id"));
                item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));
                item.setComment(feedObj.getString("comment"));
                item.setProfile_img(feedObj.getString("profile_img"));
                item.setTime(feedObj.getString("time"));


                commentsitems.add(item);
                //  Toast.makeText(getContext(),feedObj.getString("text"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            // update data in our adapter
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            // notify data changes to list adapater

        } else {


        }


        //listAdapter.addAll(feedItems);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void parseJsonLikes(JSONObject response) {
    int success;

    try {
        success = response.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success == 1) {
            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("likes");

            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                FriendsListItem item = new FriendsListItem();
                item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));
                item.setProfImage(feedObj.getString("profile_img"));



                likesitems.add(item);
                //  Toast.makeText(getContext(),feedObj.getString("text"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            // update data in our adapter
            listAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();

            // notify data changes to list adapater
        } else {


        }


        //listAdapter.addAll(feedItems);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void parseJsonComment(JSONObject response) {
    int success;

    try {
        success = response.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success == 1) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        } else {


        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Do you have any code? In java there is 'if' keyword that is used for these sort of things :)

Comment: Please show the code if you have.

Comment: A good place to start would be creating a button in the list item layout. Then wire up a click listener and do some work when the button is pressed

Comment: Use a custom listview and set visibility of button view to VISIBLE or GONE depending upon your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, got the idea now . i'll try something and tell if it works .

Comment: I tried something but it didn't work ,the problem i have is when i click to see the posts how to know the get the position of every item .what i want to do is to test if the id of user who posted that post is the same user connected but to do this i need to get the positions of items